# How to distinguish devices with the same vendor's id

Tags: linux, usb, filenames

I have two USB devices (rs232 to USB) connected.They have the same vendor's ID.During the boot they're associated randomly to /dev/ttyUSB0 and to /dev/ttyUSB1.Is there a way to associate each device with its proper file name?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry - posting a new answer. Best method I can think of if you have physical access to the host, would be to plug one device in, scan and see what device name is assigned to it, then plug in the next and get the new device name for that. My previous answer doesn't help you along, so I had it removed.